# op-amp differential amplifier - output is the same with Vcc

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm tring to use a OP-AMP LM358P as a differential amplifier.
The circuit I'm using is like below;
[image]

According to what I've study and expectations of SPICS, the out-put should be about 2.5(V1-V2). To be specific, I would V1, v2 will be 0~3.3V and the expected output is proportional -8V~+8V. However, the actual circuit provides constant V which is the same with Vcc voltage; actually bit less than the Vcc when I tried with 12V and 24V as Vcc.

So, what could be the possible cause that makes the circuit does not work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the + and - input swapped (positive feedback, rather than negative) so it will snap to as close as it can get to either rail, depending on the inputs.